# Corporate Windows Domain: How to restrict selection of Wallpapers

Tags: domain, group-policy, desktop

All my users workstations are part of our corporate domain.  Currently we have a group policy that forces the company wallpaper through to all workstations.  This is working fine.  However, we have a number of users who have asked if we can provide alternative colour wallpapers - we are fine with allowing this as a number of them have impaired vision and find the current colour dificult to use.

I don't want to allow unrestricted changes but it would be nice to offer a limited number of wallpapers and allow the users to choose from the selection.

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to allow arbitrary wallpapers? In my experience, few things are more important to some users than the ability to put their family or pet on their computer desktop. As long as their isn't a good reason for this that you can communicate to your users, it will only help to create the impression of a hostile IT department.

Comment: Yes there is a specific reason - the environment is frequently visited by clients and we would prefer to keep things 'tidy'.  This has been explained to the staff who are all happy with the policy.

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple GPOs for each wallpaper with different wallpapers that you want to apply. Create groups in AD that apply to the wallpaper they want then write a WMI filter and apply it to expected GPO so that the GPO can only apply to the specified group.